# Finding the probability of an unknown constant

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the value of the unknown constant number and the probability of the length less than it.

The question is "A unit length, thin rod breaks in two places, each break independently uniformly distributed on [0,1]. Let a be a small number. Show that the probability that one of the three pieces into which the rod breaks has length less than a is approximately ka as a -> $0$ where k is a constant you should determine.

I know I can use Taylor expansion to find the approximation of a but it would be impossible to draft out an equation if a is unknown. How can I find the value of a? And how would it be possible to find the probability from knowing the value of a?

Update: Thx for everyone's help. So what I've got now is that k must be smaller than 1 in order for the rod to be shorter than a. But I'm kinda stuck in here now as I'm not sure how does it related to finding the probability?

Comment: There is no value for $a$.  $a$ is a variable which is just required to be small and positive.  Work it out for, say, $a=\frac 1{10}$.  Then do $\frac 1{100}$, and so on.  Until you see a pattern you can prove generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the positions of the two breaks be $x$ and $y$.  The sample space is the unit square.  Having one piece less than $a$ in length occurs when $x \lt a, y \lt a, x \gt 1-a, y \gt 1-a, -a \lt x-y \lt a$.  A figure is below.  Compute the area of this region, the outer frame and the main diagonal, in terms of $a$.  There will be a term proportional to $a$ with a subtraction proportional to $a^2$ for the overlaps in the corners.  You are supposed to neglect the term proportional to $a^2$.
[image]

Comment: No.  The probability is the area I indicated out of the area of the square.  In fact, $k$ will be greater than $1$.  If you ignore the diagonal, what is the area of the outer border as a function of $a$?  You have missed the point that any of the three pieces can be shorter than $a$.  That is where all the different inequalities I gave came from.  You need to understand that.